# HTML tables hide <td> cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I know everyone is going to tell me not to use tables and I get it, but it works in this simple application except I am trying to hide a few  cells. Can't seem to figure out how to prevent them from displaying. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

```
<div id="memtab">
    <table>
        <tr class="head">
            <td>Head 1</td>
            <td>Head 2</td>
            <td>Head 3</td>
            <td>Head 4</td>
            <td>Head 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hide</td>
            <td>Hide</td>
            <td>Hide</td>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>Display</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables *should* be used in certain scenarios - such as when you want to display tabular data - but they are often misused for page layout.

You can hide cells using `visibility: hidden`.

A side note, learn about html table elements such as `thead`, `tbody` and `th`. They will help structure your table with greater semantic meaning.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  background: yellow;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="memtab">
    <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Head 1</th>
              <th>Head 2</th>
              <th>Head 3</th>
              <th>Head 4</th>
              <th>Head 5</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hide">Hide</td>
                <td class="hide">Hide</td>
                <td class="hide">Hide</td>
                <td>Display</td>
                <td>Display</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't see to be working. The cells are empty, but the boxes are still visible.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `border: none;` on the hidden `td`s

Comment: Ok seems to be working in your example. Not working in my code yet, but this must because of something thing else going on. Will check my work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility: hidden;` to your `<td>`'s style

Instead of just make 3 or more style in one cell, why would we use `colspan` to make our cell easier to config?

```
<tr>
    <td colspan=2 style="visibility:collapse">Hide</td>
    <td>Display</td>
    <td>Display</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is closer, the the main box still surrounds the table.

Comment: Hmm still broken